# Stubbing a method on a spyk object calls the original method immediately

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

for example the method

```
   class SomeClass() {
       fun login(listener: (Boolean) -> Unit ) {
            do some async logic and then call the listener with the result
      }
   }

   val spy = spyk(SomeClass())  {

          val completion = slot<(Boolean) -> Unit>()
         //this immediately calls the original login method
         every { login(capture(completion)) } answers {
              completion.captured.invoke(true)
         }
     }
```

trying to stub the login method immediately invokes it.

Do you know how to just stub it and not invoke it?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the Mockk,  maybe [relaxed-mock](https://mockk.io/#relaxed-mock) ?

Comment: i do not see an option to put relaxed on a spy. I do not need a mock, I need a spy, i want to mock partial functionality and keep the rest original

Comment: i used relaxed mock and got the same result